# Running MongoDB Server During Production

Tags: mongodb

Hello I'm new to MongoDB, is it recommended to run our MongoDB on our server during production? or is it neccessary to use provided services such as MongoDB atlas or MLAB for MongoDB database? If there are downsides of running our own MongoDB server, please mention it and include any potential solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference. It mainly depends on your strategy and requirements (e.g. data protection and privacy).

Cloud might be more expensive or cheaper, it depends on your application and resource requirements.

When you deploy the MongoDB on your premises then you have to take care also about backup and system administration and you may have to develop MongoDB admin skills in your team.

In the cloud solution these topics are included, you can focus just on your application.